# PostgreSQL - Aggregate attributes from different columns recursively

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

| id_start | id_end |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |

I want to collect elements who are "connected" like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. (in an array for example)

I tried a recursive query like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE q_rec AS (
    SELECT id_start,
           id_end
    FROM my_table
    UNION
    SELECT t.id_start
           t.id_end
    FROM       my_table t
    INNER JOIN q_rec r ON r.id_start = t.id_end
) 
SELECT *
FROM q_rec;
```

But how can I aggregate them in an array despite they are not in the same column ?

Comment: Looks like a recursive query can deal with it. Have you already attempted any code to solve this problem?

Comment: I edit my post with a recursive CTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach gathers all ids in the recursive query, as a table. Then applies aggregation.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT id_start AS first_id, 
         id_start AS id
  FROM tab t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tab t2 WHERE t1.id_start = t2.id_end)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT cte.first_id,
         tab.id_end
  FROM       cte
  INNER JOIN tab
          ON cte.id = tab.id_start
)
SELECT first_id, 
       ARRAY_AGG(id) AS ids
FROM cte
GROUP BY first_id
```

**Output**:

| first_id | ids |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [1,2,3,4] |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3w2Hid1Vv33Pnu3d7nfcu8/0).

Comment: Clever, get start id is a good info to add.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I'm assuming you know the start and end elements:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
  SELECT id_start, id_end, ARRAY[id_start, id_end] AS chain
  FROM your_table
  WHERE id_start = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT your_table.id_start, your_table.id_end, r.chain || your_table.id_end
  FROM your_table JOIN r ON your_table.id_start = r.id_end
)
SELECT chain FROM r WHERE id_end = 4;
```

Comment: The constraint is that I don't know start and end ids.

Comment: Do you have loops? 1->2, 2->3, 3->1?

Comment: Probably the issue of beginning points can be solved with an `EXISTS` clause in the base step of the recursion. Other than that, this solution should do it, or something very similar to it.

Comment: @Horaciux No loops